# Show value in Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, activeadmin, formtastic

I am trying to show the value of an attribute via its id with formtastic. I have two models hat are setup like this

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :members
attr_accessible :membership_type

end

class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :membership
accepts_nested_attributes_for :membership
attr_accessible :membership_id, :forename, :middlename, :surname, :house_no, :house_name, :street, :town, :postcode, :home_tel, :mobile_tel, :work_tel, :email
end
```

My index view is set up like this so far

```
index do
column :forename
column :middlename
column :surname
column :house_no
column :house_name
column :street
column :town
column :postcode
column :home_tel
column :mobile_tel
column :work_tel
column :email
column :membership 

default_actions
```

end

but the value for the membership is output as

```
#<Membership:0x007f2c2064c370>
```

How would i get the actual value so it will say "Student" for example

Normally i would do something like this i guess

```
<% @members.each do |m| %>
<%= m.forname%>
<%= m.surname%>

<% m.memberships.each do |s| %>
<%= s.membership_type%>


<% end %>
```

but cant figure it out within formtastic

Thanks

Comment: I see that you mentioned formtastic, but the views you shared are for the index. What is it you want to accomplish with formtastic? Any examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
column 'Membership type' do |member|
    "#{member.membership.membership_type}".html_safe
end
column 'Other members' do |member|
    member.membership.members.each() do |m|
      "#{m.forname} #{m.surname}<br/>".html_safe
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

ActiveAdmin tries its best to find a [display name](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/388ed07e477af5f5644d0c30cd45b4377c886dd7/lib/active_admin/view_helpers/display_helper.rb#L7) for your objects using a [list of possible attributes](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/388ed07e477af5f5644d0c30cd45b4377c886dd7/lib/active_admin/application.rb#L84-L91):

- :display_name
- :full_name
- :name
- :username
- :login
- :title
- :email

To ensure your Membership object has a recognizable name throughout the system you can add one of those attributes as a method to Membership:

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :members
  attr_accessible :membership_type

  def display_name
    membership_type
  end
end
```

Alternatively, you can do like Michał Albrycht suggests and configure views to perform custom rendering for the membership column.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Cmaresh. Problem is solved. **[This](https://github.com/Mashpy/esl_jobs/commit/91167d94f585bac5e41b8d86cbdfa30ef54133ae)** is the commit link where i solved the problem in my project. Any one can see the source code and can easily understand how to solve the problem.